# Why 'windows effects' setting not working in Deepin 15.11?

Tags: linux-distro

I have install Deepin in my desktop (Dual core, 2GB RAM) and it installed successful but the desktop is not as it has. `Deepin setting pannel` transparency is not working and as well the `Windows effects` setting is not working.
I have see for updates and update it to latest version of of Deepin nothing works so help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

had same issue just changed graphic drivers to intel and problem fixed